# JavaScript : Can anyone give an example when callback in callback (Pyramid of Doom) is needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, dynamic-script-loading

The below code does callback inside a callback. Why this is needed? Why can't it be 3 separate calls? Note loadScript just going to create a style tag and add script passed to the src attribute dynamically.

```
loadScript('/my/script.js', function(script) {

    loadScript('/my/script2.js', function(script) {

        loadScript('/my/script3.js', function(script) {

            // ...continue after all scripts are loaded
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: You use callbacks so that you can execute some code after an arbitrary amount of processing time is taken by an asynchronous process. For example, your `loadScript` function takes a script in a callback, that means it loads the script **then** it calls the callback. If you were to do them seperately, all of them would load at once, and you would not be able to accurately pinpoint when all three finished.

Comment: when something from each call is needed.... A makes a call and gets data and B uses A's data, and C uses B's data. It can be common when you have a lot of microservices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: what is a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309321/javascript-what-is-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are using callbacks to ensure that each script completes loading before the next one. They are chained so that all three scripts have to be loaded before continuing the code. The reason this is important is that scripts block the rest of rendering/execution while they load.
You can also use async/promise syntax to hold the loading in each line if you want to pretty this up:

```
const loader = new Loader({
    src: 'cdn.segment.com/analytics.js',
    global: 'Segment',
})

// scriptToLoad will now be a reference to window.Segment
const scriptToLoad = await loader.load()

// https://timber.io/snippets/asynchronously-load-a-script-in-the-browser-with-javascript/
```

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

https://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/